# Как в WPF убрать в левом нижнем углу значки микрофона и обновить?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в WPF убрать в левом нижнем углу значки микрофона и обновить? 
Убрал верхнюю панель, сняв галочку "Включить средства отладки пользовательского интерфейса для XAML", но не могу понять, как убрать эти значки.

Comment: какая у вас VS?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: только в режиме отладки, правильно?

Comment: Да, в режиме отладки

Comment: не пробовали обновить VS?

Comment: У меня последняя версия

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил, что у меня не только в visual studio такие значки, но в некоторых других приложениях. Возможно это из-за geforce experience? Сейчас попробую отключить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была из-за приложения xbox от Microsoft, в настройках нужно было отключить живую плитку